# Iterate over a column and find the sum

Tags: r

I need to sum the results of three different parameters (1-3) into a new column called "New". The results should only be added if the SiteID is equal to 'One','Two','Three','Four','Five' & the date of sample collection is the same for each parameter. The time of collection does not matter as long as the date is the same.

I am a novice in R and tried If, While, and For loops but did not get very far...

Thank you

Below is what the results should look like:
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjP77.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sum a variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group)

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to do a group by 'SiteID', 'Date' column and then `mutate` to create a new column which is the `sum` of 'Result'

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
         group_by(SiteID, Date) %>%
         mutate(New = sum(Result))
```